# How can I use devcards with reagent / secretary routing?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to put a simple site together to demonstrate a ClojureScript library with a couple of "pages", each of which contains several examples.

I used a leiningen template to make a project with devcards, routing etc.

I now have the default boilerplate :

```
(defn home-page []
  [:div [:h2 "Welcome to site"]
   [:div [:a {:href "/about"} "go to about page"]]]  )

(defn about-page []
  [:div [:h2 "About site"]
   [:div [:a {:href "/"} "go to the home page"]]])
```

I now want to put some devcards into these "pages".

However, just putting a defcard either next to or inside one of these functions doesn't seem to add it to the page.

So can devcards be used in this context? If so, where / how do I put them?

Comment: Have you tried to create a function like `(defcard my-first-card
  (sab/html [:h1 "Devcards is freaking awesome!"]))` and call it as an html element? `(defn home-page []
  [:div [:h2 "Welcome to site"]
   [:div [:a {:href "/about"} "go to about page"] (my-first-card) ]]  )`